# Procedure for boarding flight from Mexico to the US with dual citizenship (Mexican-Italian)?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, mexico

I have been invited to travel to the US in June and my trip would be fully paid for.

I live in Mexico but I was born in Italy and have dual citizenship. I would like to  use my Italian passport to enter and exit the US under the Visa Waiver Program and I already have an approved ESTA application to do so.

I have doubts regarding what to do when leaving Mexico. According to the ESTA website, I would need to board the plane using my Italian passport, but if I only use that for check-in, they would consider me a foreigner and ask me for my FMM paperwork. Of course I could show them my Mexican passport as proof of residency, but could they use both to process my flight? With my Mexican passport, I would fill the "Solicitud de salida del territorio nacional para mexicanos", a small paper that is used to track nationals when leaving Mexico. But, would the airline accept my Italian passport and my Mexican passport and paperwork at the same time for boarding? Is this even possible?
I do not know where to find more information.